# Filtered table through Calculate Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have filtered the table by creating a new one in the following way:

```
CalculateTable(Sales,Filter(Sales,Sales[Amount]>500), FILTER(Sales,Sales[Product] IN {"A","B"})
```

However, beside the general consition (Amount>500), I also need to add a condition with if. If product is A, then Amount must be more than 600, if product is B, then Amount must be greater than 650.

I have tried something like `CalculateTable(Sales,Filter(Sales,Sales[Amount]>500),Filter(Sales,Sales[Amount]>600) IF Sales[Product]="A")`

but it is not working. Could you help me, please?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast solution will be:

```
FILTER(
    Sales
   ,[Amount]>500 && [Product]="A" || [Amount]>600 && [Product]="B"
)
```

FILTER, CALCULATE, CALCULATETABLE costs resources and it is influencing speed of a measure. So, try to use it as less as possible.